# Why does boost asio function expires_from_now() cancel a deadline_timer?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, boost-asio

When I try to get (not set!) the current expiry time using
boost expires_from_now() is seems to actually cancel the timer,
yet it actually runs as expected, but does finally not call the handler.

Or put in other words, when accessing a deadline_timer with expires_from_now()
it will call the handler immediately and not call the handler when it expires.

Please consider the following code and corresponding output:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp> 
#include <boost/thread.hpp> 
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_io.hpp>
#include <iostream> 

using namespace boost::posix_time;
using namespace std;

void handler1(const boost::system::error_code &ec) 
{ 
    if (ec == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
    {
        std::cout << microsec_clock::local_time() << " Handler1: Timer 1 was cancelled or retriggered." << std::endl; 
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << microsec_clock::local_time() << " Handler1: expired." << std::endl; 
    }
} 

boost::asio::io_service io_service1; 

class Mytimer {
public:
    Mytimer();
    void startTimer();
    void runTimerThread();
    bool isRunning();
private:
    bool m_isRunning;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer* m_pTimer;
    boost::thread* m_pThread;
};

Mytimer::Mytimer()
  : m_pTimer(NULL),
    m_pThread(NULL)
{
    m_pTimer = new boost::asio::deadline_timer(io_service1); 
    m_pTimer->async_wait(handler1); 
}

void Mytimer::runTimerThread()
{
    io_service1.run();
}

void Mytimer::startTimer()
{
    m_pThread = new boost::thread(&Mytimer::runTimerThread, this);
    m_pTimer->expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(10));
}

bool Mytimer::isRunning()
{

    time_duration td = m_pTimer->expires_from_now();
    if (td.total_seconds() > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main() 
{ 
    time_facet *facet = new time_facet("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S%f");
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale(std::cout.getloc(), facet));

    cout << microsec_clock::local_time() << " before timer construction" << endl;
    Mytimer timer;
    cout << microsec_clock::local_time() << " before startTimer()" << endl;
    timer.startTimer();
    cout << microsec_clock::local_time() << " IsRunning: " << timer.isRunning() << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        sleep(1);
        cout << microsec_clock::local_time() << " IsRunning: " << timer.isRunning() << endl;
    }
}
```

> 20120412 22:41:45689235 before timer construction
>   20120412 22:41:45689514 before startTimer()
>   20120412 22:41:45689619 IsRunning: 1
>   20120412 22:41:45689693 Handler1: Timer 1 was cancelled or retriggered.
>   20120412 22:41:46689792 IsRunning: 1
>   20120412 22:41:47689994 IsRunning: 1
>   20120412 22:41:48690179 IsRunning: 1
>   20120412 22:41:49690375 IsRunning: 1
>   20120412 22:41:50690530 IsRunning: 1
>   20120412 22:41:51690712 IsRunning: 1
>   20120412 22:41:52690884 IsRunning: 1
>   20120412 22:41:53691069 IsRunning: 1
>   20120412 22:41:54691236 IsRunning: 0
>   20120412 22:41:55691428 IsRunning: 0
>   20120412 22:41:56691614 IsRunning: 0
>   20120412 22:41:57691810 IsRunning: 0
>   20120412 22:41:58692001 IsRunning: 0
>   20120412 22:41:59692193 IsRunning: 0
>   20120412 22:42:00692364 IsRunning: 0
>   20120412 22:42:01692542 IsRunning: 0
>   20120412 22:42:02692706 IsRunning: 0
>   20120412 22:42:03692886 IsRunning: 0
>   20120412 22:42:04693071 IsRunning: 0
>   20120412 22:42:05693267 IsRunning: 0
>   20120412 22:42:06693465 IsRunning: 0

Comment: I think there are two problems here: First in the constructor the timer is called without any expiration duration, so it will actually expire immediately. Second when the member function re-starts the timer, there is no handler. So expires_from_now still works (as you can see the 1 changes to 0 after 10 seconds), but the handler will never be called, because there is none associated.

Comment: I'll keep the question open for now, maybe someone can confirm my conclusions.

Comment: your code snippet is very bloated and filled with a lot of junk that is not pertinent to the question and/or makes it harder to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> When I try to get (not set!) the current expiry time using boost
>   expires_from_now() is seems to actually cancel the timer, yet it
>   actually runs as expected, but does finally not call the handler.

this assumption is incorrect. When you create your `deadline_timer`

```
m_pTimer = new boost::asio::deadline_timer(io_service1);
m_pTimer->async_wait(handler1);
```

you've told it to expire immediately. Then, when you start your `io_service`

```
m_pThread = new boost::thread(&Mytimer::runTimerThread, this);
```

you subsequently invoke

```
m_pTimer->expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(10));
```

which as the documentation [describes clearly](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/expires_from_now/overload2.html), this will cancel any outstanding handlers, emphasis added is mine

> This function sets the expiry time. **Any pending asynchronous wait
>   operations will be cancelled**. The handler for each cancelled operation
>   will be invoked with the `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted` error
>   code.

To resolve this, change your `Mytimer::startTimer()` method as follows

```
--- timer4.cc.orig  2012-04-13 11:18:47.000000000 -0500
+++ timer4.cc   2012-04-13 11:16:54.000000000 -0500
@@ -1,4 +1,3 @@
-
 #include <boost/asio.hpp> 
 #include <boost/thread.hpp> 
 #include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
@@ -39,7 +38,6 @@
     m_pThread(NULL)
 {
     m_pTimer = new boost::asio::deadline_timer(io_service1); 
-    m_pTimer->async_wait(handler1); 
 }

 void Mytimer::runTimerThread()
@@ -49,8 +47,9 @@

 void Mytimer::startTimer()
 {
-    m_pThread = new boost::thread(&Mytimer::runTimerThread, this);
     m_pTimer->expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(10));
+    m_pTimer->async_wait(handler1); 
+    m_pThread = new boost::thread(&Mytimer::runTimerThread, this);
 }

 bool Mytimer::isRunning()
```

which results in the expected behavior

```
mbp:stackoverflow samm$ ./a.out
20120413 11:17:22922529 before timer construction
20120413 11:17:22923155 before startTimer()
20120413 11:17:22923530 IsRunning: 1
20120413 11:17:23924702 IsRunning: 1
20120413 11:17:24925971 IsRunning: 1
20120413 11:17:25927320 IsRunning: 1
20120413 11:17:26928715 IsRunning: 1
20120413 11:17:27929969 IsRunning: 1
20120413 11:17:28930601 IsRunning: 1
20120413 11:17:29931843 IsRunning: 1
20120413 11:17:30933098 IsRunning: 1
20120413 11:17:31934366 IsRunning: 0
20120413 11:17:32923594 Handler1: expired.
20120413 11:17:32934692 IsRunning: 0
20120413 11:17:33935922 IsRunning: 0
20120413 11:17:34936638 IsRunning: 0
20120413 11:17:35937905 IsRunning: 0
20120413 11:17:36939133 IsRunning: 0
20120413 11:17:37940407 IsRunning: 0
20120413 11:17:38941043 IsRunning: 0
20120413 11:17:39942319 IsRunning: 0
20120413 11:17:40942662 IsRunning: 0
20120413 11:17:41943989 IsRunning: 0
20120413 11:17:42945284 IsRunning: 0
20120413 11:17:43946555 IsRunning: 0
mbp:stackoverflow samm$
```

Comment: Your output opens another question. How do I design a IsRunning() member function which does not return 0 while the timer is still running. One thing which comes to my mind is using a boolean private flag within the handler which is set to false in the member handler function. Changing the total_seconds to total_nanoseconds might be another option.

Comment: @Michael it's not obvious to me what you're hoping to accomplish with that approach. A `deadline_timer` will expire after the time given, or be cancelled. In which case, the solution is to check the error given to the completion handler.

Comment: as you can see from your output above, the IsRunning member funciton returns false before the deadline_timer actually expires. So for me this check is still not correct. I think one possible approach is to have a local flag, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The following code now has the correct deadline_timer initialization,
and has a private bool flag, which allows to determine,
if the timer is currently running. It also has a member local handler.

```
class Mytimer {
public:
    Mytimer();
    void startTimer(int timeDelaySecs);
    void cancelTimer();
    void runTimerThread();
    bool isRunning();
    void timerHandler(const boost::system::error_code& ec); 
private:
    bool m_isRunning;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer* m_pTimer;
    boost::thread* m_pThread;
};

Mytimer::Mytimer()
    : m_pTimer(NULL),
      m_pThread(NULL)
{
    m_pTimer = new boost::asio::deadline_timer(io_service1); 
}

void Mytimer::runTimerThread()
{
    io_service1.run();
}

void Mytimer::startTimer(int timeDelaySecs)
{
    m_pTimer->expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(timeDelaySecs));
    m_pTimer->async_wait(boost::bind(&Mytimer::timerHandler, this, _1)); 
    m_pThread = new boost::thread(&Mytimer::runTimerThread, this);
    m_isRunning = true;
}

bool Mytimer::isRunning()
{
    return m_isRunning;
}

void Mytimer::timerHandler(const boost::system::error_code& ec) 
{ 
    if (ec == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
    {
        std::cout << microsec_clock::local_time() << " Handler1: Timer 1 was cancelled or retriggered." << std::endl; 
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << microsec_clock::local_time() << " Handler1: expired." << std::endl; 
    }
    m_isRunning = false;
}
```